# Is there a shortcut to open resharper menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

When i type something and i want to open the little menu integrated in visual studio i press CTRL + . 
[image]

Unfortunately this menu has very few options, and the things I need are in the Resharper menu (which is represented by the red lamp on left)
I want him to generate empty method..

The way I do it now is by clicking on the lamp, and then choosing the option i want (like generate method, add readonly to field, convert to lambda ... )

I can't find a way to open that menu otherwise and **i'm sure that some keyboard shortcut must exist.**

I know that the question seems dumb, but it will save me lots of time in the long run :)

Thank and have a good day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Shortcut for Quick Fix is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which is the same than add reference with the Visual Studio scheme.

You can change it in `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`, look for the command named `ReSharper_QuickFix` (I also heard it was renamed to `ReSharper_AltEnter` in some versions).

Comment: @OopsUser Then you could also configure the `ReSharper_GoToFile` command if you don't have it (usually mapped to CTRL + SHIFT + T), it's the only other ReSharper shortcut I _frequently_ use.

Comment: It's *Resharper_AltEnter* from from v. 9 and forward.

Answer (score 5):

You want the Action List.  To access it hit..

> Alt + Enter

Here is the [full list of R# commands](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)

Here is more info on the [Action List](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Actions_List.html).

Answer (score 0):

The below extension is for VS2012 will helps you to see the available shortcuts. Sometimes this will suites for your needs

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2964c90-68e2-4ddd-861a-bd66e5cd4434